# Does the article change the meaning of the expression "Student with [a?] physics background"?

Tags: meaning, indefinite-article

I have heard natives say both

> student with physics background

and

> student with a physics background

so I assume both expressions are grammatical.

Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: I don't like the article-less version very much. I suggest you avoid it. To me, the only "meaning" it conveys is that the speaker/writer is sloppy and/or not well-educated (or simply "not a native speaker").

Comment: I agree that the article should always be used. I *believe* it's ungrammatical to leave it out (aside from in headlinese)—but I'm having difficulty forming a cogent argument.

Comment: Are you sure you haven’t heard /seen “student**s** with physics backgrounds”? The article gets omitted when the phrase is in the plural.

Comment: @J.R. That might be it! And in case it's in a resume: "John Doe, Engineer with [a?] physics background". Do we need the article there?

Comment: @Leo - You wouldn’t need it there, either, because resumés don’t use full sentences – just informational “bullets”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Background' is a singular countable noun, so would usually need a word like 'a', 'the', 'my' or 'your'. So standard English definitely needs 'a student with a physics background'.

But there are some special contexts where articles and similar can be omitted, for example newspaper headlines and headings in articles etc (which are written sources). Imagine a university faculty committee decides to create a new part-time job for a laboratory assistant. They say 'We need *a student with a physics background*'. Then they write the advertisement, which starts 'New job available - laboratory assistant. Suit *student with physics background*'. You see the ad and you think 'I am *a student with a physics background*. I'll apply.'

Where have you heard native speakers saying 'student with physics background'?

Comment: How after reading your answer, it probably was not "I've heard" but rather "I've read". So what if we use it in writing as a subtitle for a resume: "John Doe, Engineer with [a?] physics background". Do we need the article there?

Comment: Yes. Titles, subtitles, dot points, short list items are all examples of places where articles, pronouns, auxiliary verbs can be omitted. I looked at my own resume. It includes "Experience / Skills • teaching general English at *a* private language institute in South Korea". I might have omitted the 'a', but I didn't. The more like a complete sentence, the more we have to include the 'a'. Compare: "Experience / Skills - teaching • general English at private language institute in South Korea".